# Conditional accumulating sum with a dynamic condition

Tags: r

Good afternoon
i'm trying to create an accumulating mean with a "twist" - i only want to average fields that dated before the current one (there may be field with the same date)

i succeeded doing it the "dirty way" using several custom created function but it takes too long and it's very inefficient - im pretty sure that there is a better way.

i was thinking about something along the line of:

```
averages <- DB %>% group_by(field1,field2) %>% mutate(Avg=cummean(???*value1)))
```

how do i access the current observation for `cummean`  function

the route i went was to create a logical vector for every subset with a loop

```
for (i in 1:length(datevector)-1)
    logicalvector[i] <- datevector[length(datevector)]>datevector[i]
  logicalvector[length(datevector)]=F
```

and use that in another function to calculate the mean

a simple example is:

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:5,Date=as.Date(c("2013-08-02","2013-08-02","2013-08-03","2013-08-03","2013-08-04")),Value=c(1,4,5,2,4))

id  Date    Value     accum mean
1  02/08/2013     1         0
2  02/08/2013     4         0
3  03/08/2013     5        2.5
4  03/08/2013     2        2.5
5  04/08/2013     4         3

Explanation:
there are no observation with a prior date for the first 2 observations so the mean is 0
the 3rd observation averages the 1st and 2nd, so does the 4th.
the 5th observation averages all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table` and `lubridate` you have this option:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
dt <- data.table(id=c(1:5))
dt$Date <- c("02/08/2013", "02/08/2013", "03/08/2013", "03/08/2013", "04/08/2013")
dt$Value <- c(1,4,5,2,4)
dt$Date <- dmy(dt$Date)

cummean <- function(d){
  if(nrow(dt[Date<d])>0)
    dt[Date<d, sum(Value)/.N]
  else 0
}

dt[, accuMean:=mapply(cummean,Date)]

#    id    Date    Value accuMean
#1:  1 2013-08-02     1      0.0
#2:  2 2013-08-02     4      0.0
#3:  3 2013-08-03     5      2.5
#4:  4 2013-08-03     2      2.5
#5:  5 2013-08-04     4      3.0
```

Solution when you have multiple values:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
dt <- data.table(id=c(1:5))
dt$Date <- c("02/08/2013", "02/08/2013", "03/08/2013", "03/08/2013", "04/08/2013")
dt$Value_1 <- c(1,4,5,2,4)
dt$Value_2 <- c(3,2,0,1,2)
dt$Value_3 <- c(4,9,3,3,3)
dt$Date <- dmy(dt$Date)

cummean <- function(d,Value){
  if(nrow(dt[Date<d])>0)
    sum(dt[Date<d, Value, with=F])/dt[Date<d, .N]
  else 0
}

n <- 3
accuMean <- paste0("accuMean_", (1:n))
for(i in 1:n){
  print(i)
  dt[, (accuMean[i]):=mapply(cummean,Date,MoreArgs = list(paste0("Value_",i)))]
}
```

Suppose you have n values named Value_i. Ten in your case, you only need to set n=10

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, allow me to challenge you with additional complication... lets say i have multiple variables(value1...value10) that i want add, do i need to use this approach for every computation? to clearify  the ```cummean```  will return multiple values and not only 1, is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

This can be implwemented as a complex self-join in SQL.  This joins to each row all rows with lesser `Date` amd for each row averages `Value` in the joined rows.  `coalesce` is used to assign 0 in the situation where the mean would otherwise be Null.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.*, coalesce(avg(b.Value), 0) as mean
  from df as a 
  left join df as b on b.Date < a.Date
  group by a.rowid")
```

giving:

```
  id       Date Value mean
1  1 2013-08-02     1  0.0
2  2 2013-08-02     4  0.0
3  3 2013-08-03     5  2.5
4  4 2013-08-03     2  2.5
5  5 2013-08-04     4  3.0
```

Comment: Thanks, that is currect, ( im using the same logic on my server), the problem is that my Df is very big and using join on it self on my personal computer exceed the memory limit  so i was searching for alternative solution. For smaller df or servers you are 100% right

Comment: By default `sqldf` uses an in-memory database but if you add the argument `dbname = tempfile()` then it will use the indicated temporary file as the database instead so R's memory limitations will not apply.